# How much do conditional operators affect performance in js?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, konvajs

I am developing a js whiteboard app. For drawing purposes I use mousedown, mousemove and mouseup events. In mousemove handler I have code like this:

```js
function handleMouseMove(tool){
  if (tool === 'pen') { drawing }
  else if (tool === 'eraser') { drawing }
  // and so on (there are 6 conditions)
}
```

So if I replace these conditions by tool handlers call, will it improve performance?
Example code:

```js
function penHandler(){
  drawing
}
function eraserHandler(){
  drawing
}
// and so on


let activeHandler = null

function handleMouseDown(tool){
  if (tool === 'pen') activeHandler = penHandler
  // and so on
}

function handleMouseMove(){
  activeHandler()
}
```

I think it does not affect performance much, but I would like to know what other people think about it.

Comment: Such micro-optimizations are definitely a waste of your time. Write code that you think is clear and easy to read and fix and extend.

Comment: I think you might it difficult to accurately measure the difference between the two options. That being said, you can use tools like https://jsbench.me/ to find out

Comment: Logical operators are lightning fast even in a relatively slow language such as JS. Where your time would be better spent in terms of optimisations would be how and when you update the DOM. That is by far the biggest bottleneck in most JS applications.